# Second page does not fully cover previous page (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I'm currently working on `Xamarin` Forms app.
My application works in full screen mode without `toolbar`. When I move from first to second page, the second page shows properly, but I still see small part of the first page on the top of application.

Screens from android application:

First page

[image]

Second page with part of first page on top

[image]

I added this annotation to MainActivity.cs

`this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);`

App.xaml.cs:

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new App3.MainPage();
    }
```

My question is, how can I show only second page on full screen?

Comment: Show all the relevant code please - e.g. rendering the button, event for creating the new page.

Comment: XF doen't provides a way to handle some behaviors individually to each page (none that I know). I had a similar trouble to open one specific page in fixed landscape mode (other pages were controlled by user configurations). I had to create a component inheriting from Content Page with the property "FixedOrientation", and a custom renderer to handle it on specific platform. I think it's the way you must go to handle the window flags on specific page

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza I'm new in Xamarin Forms, can you simplify your answer or show some sample code?

Comment: It was a comment, not an answer. But I'll try to find out how to do this code and post it like answer this time =).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an simple solution :

First, use `NavigationPage` to manages the navigation :

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

Second, in your `MainPage.xaml.cs`, hide the  `NavigationBar` :

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
    }
}
```

In your second page do the same thing :

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OhhN.gif).

Comment: Partly it solved the problem - label moved to the top but in background is blue space, probably from default status bar despite that I set full screen and used this line in first and second page constructors: NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false); Screen:https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WjE5.png

Comment: Finally I found solution. Default android background consists of white space for content and narrow blue bar behind default status bar. When I set background color in xaml whole page had one color. Thank you! :D

Comment: @RDMM, happy coding. : )